# How to query a document library with document sets by name

Tags: 2010

[image]I have a document library which documents are actually document sets each one.

The only way to diferentiate each item is with the column called name, which is actually a guid.

I need to query with that column, but in the UI, it tells me that its a file.

The next code, I tried also with type = Text. but it didnt work.

```
SPList agendaPoints = subSite.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTS_NAME);
                                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                        query.Query = string.Concat("<Where>",
                                                                         "<Eq>",
                                                                              "<FieldRef Name='Name' />",
                                                                              "<Value Type='File'>" + name + "</Value>",
                                                                        "</Eq>",
                                                                    "</Where>");



![enter code here][2]
```

The exception is:
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: One or more field types are not installed properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query with document set using **"Document Set ID"**.

see this link might be helpful for you.

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2010/09/26/querying-document-sets-using-spsitedataquery/